# How to get assets in play framework 2.7?

Tags: java, playframework, sbt

I'm trying to use AdminLTE 3 on playframework but every time I use the versioned this didn´t work.

And the content when compile is the next: 
`<script src="Action(parser=BodyParser(ignore))"></script>`.

But the code I'm using is this: `<script src="@Assets.versioned("plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js")"></script>`

I read at the docs [Assets Overview](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/AssetsOverview#The-Assets-controller) that they said I would use `Assets.at` code but I can't do it works.

*I apologize if my English is not very good.*

**EDIT:**

`GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.versioned(path="/public", file: Asset)`

That's my route for get the assets

```
name := ""
organization := ""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava, PlayEbean)

scalaVersion := "2.13.0"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  ehcache,
  javaWs,
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-guice" % "2.7.3",
  "org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.4-1202-jdbc42"
)

routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator
```

And that is my `build.sbt` file.

Comment: Hey, have you added this "GET  /assets/*file  controllers.Assets.versioned(path="/public", file: Asset)" in your routes file? if not then add it and try like this <script src="@routes.Assets.versioned("plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js")"></script>

Comment: I have edit my question with the content of the `routes` and `build.sbt` files

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found my error, I'm writting `<script src="@Assets.versioned("plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js")"></script>` but the correct route is `script src="@routes.Assets.versioned("plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js")"></script>`